# Cannot reach secondary TP-Link router without getting the configuration page for the main F@ST 3896 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have two routers:

| Router | Local IP Range | Default Gateway |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TP-Link Archer VR400 | 192.168.137.3 - 192.168.137.99 | 192.168.137.1 |
| F@ST 3896 | 192.168.137.100 - 192.168.137.244 | 192.168.137.2 |

The ethernet comes directly to the F@ST router, then I send it to the TP-Link.

The problem here is that when I try to access to the TP-Link config page, it sends me to the F@ST router, even though I've set up different default gateways.

But the main problem here is that I have a 1000Mbps connection, but the TP-Link only reaches 100Mbps even through ethernet.

Comment: You need to show your connection diagram ( or better description) and the config of the browser in relation to ip addresses and dhcp

Comment: “But the main problem here is that I have a 1000Mbps connection, but the TP-Link only reaches 100Mbps even through ethernet.” You _might_ have two questions here. The solution to the first issue might clear up the second issue. But if it doesn’t clear that up, then you might need to start a new question for the speed issue.

Comment: You are right @Giacomo1968, sorry, and im not sure if the tp-link can manage that ethernet speed (1000Mbps) :c